# Trouble with jquery remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I've been trying to update a table dynamically with jquery load() and I've ran into an issue.

The data is loaded correctly into my table with load(). However, when I try to delete the previous rows of the table and then call load() (to get the new table rows) it just appends the new table rows onto the end of the old ones.

I've ruled out that the response I get from load() contains the previous data. Load() is also called after the previous rows have been deleted, so I'm not quite sure where I've gone wrong.

Inspect element in chrome shows the table rows being correctly deleted, but when after load() is called the deleted rows re-appear.

**Javascript/Jquery code:**

```
    $("#quantity").change(function(){
  if ($('.table_row_data').length > 0)
  { 
    // if data exists, remove the rows then get the new ones
    $.when($( ".table_row_data" ).remove()).then(updateTable());
  }
  else{
    updateTable();
  }

  function updateTable()
  {
    //on change load data about prices if all other fields are set
    $("#comparison").load("GetPrices.php?var1=" + $("#var1").val()
    + "&var2=" + $("#var2").val() + "&var3=" + $("#var3").val()
    + "&var4=" + $("#var5").val(), function()
    {
      //sort table when table is loaded
      $("#myTable").tablesorter
      ({ 
      // sort price low --> high by default
      sortList: [[3,0]]
      });
    });
  }
});
```

**HTML table:**

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped tablesorter" style="display: table;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header">header_1</th>
      <th class="header">header_2</th>
      <th class="header">header_3</th>
      <th class="header headerSortDown">header_4</th>
      <th class="header">header_5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="comparison">
  <tr class="table_row_data">
    <td>title</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aa</td>
    <td>aa</td>
    <td><a href="#" target="_blank"></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table_row_data">
    <td>title</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aa</td>
    <td>aa</td>
    <td><a href="#" target="_blank"></a></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: as a side note... the `$.when()` is of no use as `remove()` does not return a promise... the `remove method is a synchronous request you you can just call `$( ".table_row_data" ).remove();updateTable();`

Comment: Ah ok, I saw it used on another answer elsewhere. That's probably what's causing the issue I imagine! Lil update calling $( ".table_row_data" ).remove();updateTable(); still results in the same issue. Will keep looking and thanks :)

Comment: I've managed to fix it by disabling sortList: [[3,0]] . Not quite sure why tablesorter is causing this problem.

Comment: Problem was with the tablesorter, well not so much tablesorter's fault. I just needed to update the table after remove the rows with jquery.

$('#myTable').trigger('update');